# Setting context and inv in interactive OCL console

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, emf, ocl

I am using the Eclipse Interactive OCL console to test the OCL examples from this [document](http://download.eclipse.org/ocl/doc/5.0.0/ocl.pdf). For testing, the example(Tutorial.xmi) provided with the link is used. The tried expressions are given below.

```
Evaluating:
self.name
Results:
'tutorial'

Evaluating:
context Book
Results:
2:1:2:7 "context" unexpected token(s)

Evaluating:
context Book inv:self.name
Results:
1:1:1:4 "inv:" misplaced construct(s)
```

Here the changes in context always shows error. Also whenever I specify inv, the same "misplaces constructs" message is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse OCL Console evaluates OCL expressions such as "self.name", not Complete OCL constructs such as "context Book inv:self.name". The context is taken from the prevailing mouse selection, which might be an EClass in a Sample Ecore Editor.

Why are you using the 5.0.0 documentation? It is over 4 years old.

Comment: 5.0 link shown up as the first result in google search. Do you have the link to the latest one?

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/OCL#Documentation.2C_Publications_and_FAQs is the proper source of information.